# How to aline the textfield and counter on the same line on flutter using maxLength?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make the counter and text on the same line or same row? when i use maxlength the counter appear below the textfield.

[image]

```
Widget _nameTextField(String hintText) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController(
        text: _template.name, 
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15)
      ),
      cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLength: 40,
      // maxLengthEnforced: true,
      validator: (val) {
        if (val.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter text.';
        } 
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (val) {
        _template.name = val;
        print(val);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add suffix text and suffixstyle to your input decoration. Like this

```
Widget _nameTextField(String hintText) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController(
        text: _template.name, 
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        suffixText: '11/40',
        suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
      ),
      cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLength: 40,
      // maxLengthEnforced: true,
      validator: (val) {
        if (val.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter text.';
        } 
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (val) {
        _template.name = val;
        print(val);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: doesnt do anything. this counter is default shown if maxLength is added.

Comment: add a counter property to input decoration and make the counter an empty container, then you can manually change your counter variables by setting the state in the Textformfield's onChange callback

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. by adding suffix and setstate to update the value when tying.

Widget _nameTextField(String hintText) {
    int nameLength = _template.name.length;

```
return TextFormField(
  controller: TextEditingController(
    text: _template.name, 
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hintText,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    suffixText: nameLength.toString() + "/ 40",
    suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    counterText: "",
  ),
  cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  autofocus: true,
  maxLength: 40,
  validator: (val) {
    if (val.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter text.';
    } 
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (val) {
    _template.name = val;
    setState(() {
      nameLength = _template.name.length;
    });
    print(val);
  },
);
```

}